# Django Rest framework pagination performance issue

Tags: python, django, rest, pagination

I have a view that inherits from ListAPIView and displays a list of objects. For performance reasons, i am trying to implement pagination. So :

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
class LargeResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 2

class RaceEventListView(CallSerializerEagerLoadingMixin, ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RaceEventListSerializer
    queryset = RaceEvent.objects.all()
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
```

Following documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Without pagination only one query is made. The `Select * from raceevent`

With pagination two queries are made. The `Select * from raceevent` and the `Select * from raceevent LIMIT 2` .

As a result, I could not achieve better performance.
What should i do, in order to limit to 1 the queries when using pagination

Comment: Where do you see the two queries being ran?

Comment: I am using django-debug-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query is for calculating the total amount of objects. The json object of the response has an attribute count...In order to calculate this value a query is made.

Comment: I see queryset = RaceEvent.objects.all(), isn't it wrong way to first get all data and then paginate. What if there are millions of the records